# Wordpress change base url for wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My word press installation resides in `public_html/cushbu` folder

and it will be accessed by  `www.example.com/cushbu`   so i have changed the base url's in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com/cushbu/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com/cushbu/');
```

Also i've edited this line `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com/cushbu/ [NC]
```

the problem is i can't access the `wp-admin` its redirected to old url

So how can i completely change the base url??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `url` in your database table called `wp_options` field's home url and site url. Change it to your new url.

Comment: let me try your answer

Comment: remove the code from wp-config.php that you have inserted before. Then wait for some tiem to reflect the changes from server. Try to access wp-admin of your site.

Comment: now, at least you are not redirected to old one right ?

Comment: i am not redirect to old one but wp-admin and some othe links are not working always throw 404 error

Comment: Here is the link for wordpress site migration from localhost to live server : [link](http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-local-to-live/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147021/discussion-between-shubham-shah-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 2):

outside of cushbu folder, in public_html folder, you should have .htaccess file modify that file with the following line.

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(cushbu)
```

and WordPress source has .htaccess file edit like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cushbu/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cushbu/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: do i need to completely remove the htaccess contents and replace it with yours??

Comment: Let me try yours

Comment: do you have any htaccess file out side of your wordpress folder?

Comment: I have done the same with my live site it's working for me properly.

Comment: I've problem only with `wp-admin` when i try to access it will redirect to old

Comment: there is one solution you can hook it by function

Comment: what changes i need to do ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the site URL and home URL in the database too. Its in the wp_options table. I hope you have database access.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Follow simple steps to replace in core database url**

1) You need to export your old database to local computer

2) Notepad++ editor or some other editor tool. replace (cntrl+H) in notepad++

3) First Find http://www.example.com/cushbu/ and Replace with new URL eg. http://www.newexample.com/cushbu/

4) Second Find without http www.example.com/cushbu/ and Replace with new URL eg. www.newexample.com/cushbu/

5) Final find any old url is present or not.if yes than replace by new url and save.

6) Import new replaced database to old database and login by wp-admin and click on Settings / Permalinks now it's done.